# What follows here: Promise.resolve().then(() => setTimeout(() => console.log(4))); Is Promise = microtasks or setTimeout = macrotasks

Tags: javascript

I was searching on a website and came across this question:
Control unit.
What follows here: Promise.resolve().then(() => setTimeout(() => console.log(4))); Is Promise = microtasks or setTimeout = macrotasks

```js
console.log(1);

setTimeout(() => console.log(2));

Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log(3));

Promise.resolve().then(() => setTimeout(() => console.log(4)));

Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log(5));

setTimeout(() => console.log(6));

console.log(7);
```

The console output is: `1 7 3 5 2 6 4`
Why is 6 executed before 4?
I want to know why, advise me, what do I lack in order not to know something like that, what else should I learn?

I expected the console output to be: `1 7 3 5 2 4 6`

Comment: I suppose the timeouts run in the order they are set

Comment: Here is a simple explanation,  if we right down each section and  place a M or T or nothing next to number,..  `T = normal Task,  M = microtask`  `1 2T 3M 4MT 5M 6T 7`   Now all not (M or T, MT) get executed -> `1 7`, next all M `3 5` next `T` `2 6`, and then lastly MT `4`  as  event loop goes   MicroTasks / Task / MircoTasks / Task..etc..